# Use Ivy to get JSTL 1.2 with Ant

Tags: ant, jstl, ivy

I'm newbie with Ivy and ant. I'm using ant with Ivy to try to get JSTL1.2. I can get it successful but **the name of the jar file is jstl**. When I use it in my jsp I got the error "The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved". But When I **change the jar file to jstl-1.2 then it works well**.

I don't know why I got this issue. Please help me. This is the dependencies I used:

[image]

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from:

```
<dependency org="jstl" name="jstl" rev="1.2"/>
```

to:

```
<dependency org="javax.servlet" name="jstl" rev="1.2"/>
```

Comment: Sorry for replying lately. I'm still get the issue when using the dependence above. :(